# What are Bounds in Branch Bound

Tags: optimization, upper-lower-bounds, mixed-integer-programming

I am looking at a video to understand branch and bound more. Specifically, the one found at this link: (21) Ch06-03 Branch and Bound Method (B&B) - YouTube.

I have two questions:

1. Around 9:44, I'm not sure why the upper bound for node 3 to 10.25, but kept at 11.02 for node 2. Shouldn't the expected upper bound be the same for all nodes at one level? Based on this article https://www.gurobi.com/resource/mip-basics/, the upper bound for node 3 should be 10.25.
   To quote the article:
   "There are two additional important values we need to introduce to complete our description of branch-and-bound. First observe that, once we have an incumbent, the objective value for this incumbent, assuming the original MIP is a minimization problem, is a valid upper bound on the optimal solution of the given MIP. That is, we know that we will never have to accept an integer solution of value higher than this value. Somewhat less obvious is that, at any time during the branch-and-bound search we also have a valid lower bound, sometimes call the best bound. **This bound is obtained by taking the minimum of the optimal objective values of all of the current leaf nodes.**"
2. I am dealing with a minimization problem rather than a maximization one as shown in the video. So in this case, would my Upper Bound be the best integer solution found so far and would the lower bound will be best value for the relaxed problem or best value overall i.e. considers both the objective value for the relaxed solution and feasible solutions?
3. Any recommended books for optimization in particular branch and bound?

Answer (score 1):

For a minimization problem:

- The **lower** bound for each branch-and-bound node arises from solving the linear programming relaxation at that node.
- The **minimum** of **lower** bounds (across all active leaf nodes) is a **lower** bound on the optimal objective value of the original problem.
- Every integer feasible solution provides an **upper** bound on the optimal objective value of the original problem.

For a maximization problem:

- The **upper** bound for each branch-and-bound node arises from solving the linear programming relaxation at that node.
- The **maximum** of **upper** bounds (across all active leaf nodes) is an **upper** bound on the optimal objective value of the original problem.
- Every integer feasible solution provides a **lower** bound on the optimal objective value of the original problem.

Comment: When you say all active leaf nodes does this include nodes that contain feasible solutions and relaxed solutions or does this mean only nodes that contain relaxed solutions? If the former, this contradicts what is shown in the video, so I am assuming he made a mistake.

Comment: The "across all active leaf nodes" is about the LP bound, irrespective of integer feasible solutions.  The active leaf nodes are the nodes that have not been pruned or branched.

Comment: Ok, so one final question which should hopefully ensure that I understand everything. Would the values of the upper bounds be correct in this [image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkuqGp7L6Ay2jPJ3kQunRBv0my7-wQ).

Comment: That link doesn't work.

Comment: Try this one: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkuqGp7L6Ay2jPJ3kQunRBv0my7-wQ

Comment: No, the upper bound column is not correct, and so the gap column is also incorrect.  After you solve the LP relaxation for node 2, its upper bound is 10.25, but node 3 inherits an upper bound of 11.02 from its parent node (the root node), so the global upper bound is max(10.25, 11.02) = 11.02.  After you solve the LP relaxation for node 3, its upper bound changes to 9.25, and the global upper bound changes to max(10,25, 9.25) =10.25.

Comment: Ok, I get it now, I think I am didn't realize that node 3 will inherit the the upper bound  from its parent at the point of solving for node 2 since node 3 isn't solved for as yet.

Comment: Sorry, but one last question, I thought I understood everything until I was looking at this example (Figure 1) in this link: https://hhexiy.github.io/docs/papers/ilp-bb.pdf. On the Right Hand Side, when x = 1 and y = 12/5, the local lb = -22/5 and after comparing with the INF node, the global lb becomes -22/5. However, on the Left Hand Side, when x = 1 and y = 1, the local lb = -3 but the global lb at that level is -16/3. Shouldn't it be -3 after comparing with the INF node at that level?

Comment: The blue arrows are a bit misleading.  Later the text mentions that the nodes are processed in DFS order, so the left nodes are processed before the right ones.

Comment: Ok so since they processed the left side first, then at the end of the search tree on the left hand side prior to the nodes being fathomed, the global lb will be the min(-3, -16/3). The -16/3 comes from the fact that the node where x = 5/3 and y = 2 isn't explored as yet. However, after branching from this node, the only active node is the one where x = 1 and y = 12/5, hence the global lb = -22/5. And finally the last two nodes are processed similarly to the children nodes from the root node. Can you kindly confirm if I am correct in my analysis.

Comment: No, before the node with $x=5/3$ and $y=2$ is explored, the lower bound of that node is $-13/2$, inherited from its parent (the root node).